ASP.NET Core Windows authentication - how to fail authentication for users that pass authentication but don't have specific app business roles?
I have an intranet ASP.NET Core web app deployed in IIS that uses Windows authentication. This app has been converted from an ASP.NET MVC 5 & webforms app.
The ASP.NET Core app uses an IClaimsTransformer implementation to determine certain business roles that an user has within the application. The roles are added as claims of type role using the mechanism described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/claims?view=aspnetcore-8.0#extend-or-add-custom-claims-using-iclaimstransformation.
If the user doesn't have any business roles, then he cannot access the application.
How can I return a 401 - Unauthorized if the user doesn't have any business roles? I don't want the user to even hit any authorization point.
The old app implemented a RoleProvider class and whenever the user didn't have any roles, he was prompted for password repeatedly. This behaviour was baked into that version of the framework. I want to do the same. But currently, in the .NET Core version, the app hits authorization points, they fail and they return 403.
Here is the code from Program.cs:
using log4net.Config;
using System.Reflection;
using log4net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;


using MicroKnights.Log4NetHelper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// AddLog4Net comes from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore
builder.Logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);

var log = LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetType());

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMvcOptions(
    options =>
    {
    })
  .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
  .AddNewtonsoftJson(
    options =>
    {
    });;

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddNegotiate()
  ;

builder.Services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, AppClaimsTransformer>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
  options.IOTimeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
  options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
  options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

  options.FallbackPolicy = //options.DefaultPolicy;    
    new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
      .RequireRole(RolesConstants.DefaultRole)
      .Build();
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else 
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
  app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/home/status/{0}");

app.UseRouting();
app.UseSession();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

TIA

To me it doesn't feel logical that you would fail authentication in this case because you do know who the user is.
The problem is authorization, they don't have the needed rights.
Separate these concerns by having authentication provide claims that indicate if the user has a certain role or not, and then add a default authorization policy that checks for that role.
You can see an example of a default authorization policy here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0#require-authenticated-users

Ok. That's how it works right now. I am more concerned about security. I don't want users that have nothing to do with the app to be authenticated and try out stuff - even though I know their actions will be rejected. I want to keep them out. If I were to use a metaphor, let's say you have a city surrounded by a wall and users are people that might or might not have a permit to buy something inside the walls. I don't want to let them inside the city if they don't have the permit to buy something. Maybe I am overthinking it.

If a user doesn't have any business roles, an appropriate http response code would be 403. You know who the user is but they dont have authority.
But if you want to mimic the previous behavior you should take a look at the NegotiateEvents exposed via the NegotiateOptions which could be defined on the AddNegotiate extension.
This will indicate that there was a failure during authentication, returning a 401 http status code.
services
.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate(s => s.Events = new NegotiateEvents
{
    OnAuthenticated = context =>
    {
        if (!context.Principal.Claims.Any(s => s.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && s.Value == RolesConstants.DefaultRole))
        {
            context.Fail("Not a valid user");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
})


I tried the code in development using IIS Express and the OnAuthenticated event is not fired. I put a breakpoint on the line with if(!context.Principla... and the execution doesn't stop there.

I found this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21557

Looks like the api only works in kestrel. Thats a bummer. Easiest is just to accept that 403  is the correct status code for this scenario and go from there.
